# horizontal space of shaded box

Tags: tables, shadows

When I was searching for some answers about shaded environment, I found on internet interesting code which I little changed to adopt for my needs. I put bellow small example

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\scrollmode
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\setlength{\OuterFrameSep}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\title{Test File}

\begin{abstract}
In this paper I test shaded environment.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\newenvironment{Shaded}{%
\def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep0pt \colorbox{shadecolor}}%
  \MakeFramed {\FrameRestore}}%
 {\endMakeFramed}

\newenvironment{framedPage}[1][\hsize]
{\MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\newenvironment{shadedPage}[1][\hsize]
{
\def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep0pt \colorbox{shadecolor}}%
\MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\begin{framedPage}[.5\textwidth]
\setlength{\parindent}{4mm}
To prove the theorem
it is sufficient to show that
at least one transformation of left-side representation is defined for any two bases
and this transformation is unique.

Homomorphism $a$ operating on basis $e$ has form
\[
e'_i=e_i* a
\]
where $e'$ is coordinate matrix of vector $e'_i$
relative basis $h$ and
$e$ is coordinate matrix of vector
$e_i$ relative basis $h$.
Therefore, coordinate matrix of image of basis equal to
produc.
Since the theorem,
matrices $g$ and $e$ are nonsingular. Therefore, matrix
is the matrix of automorphism mapping basis $e$
to basis $e'$.

Suppose elements $g_1$, $g_2$ of group $G$ and basis $e$ satisfy equation
\[
e* g_1=e* g_2
\]
Since theorems,
we get $g_1=g_2$.
This proves statement of theorem.
\end{framedPage}


\begin{framedPage}[.5\textwidth]
\setlength{\parindent}{4mm}
To prove the theorem
it is sufficient to show that
at least one transformation of left-side representation is defined for any two bases
and this transformation is unique.

Homomorphism $a$ operating on basis $e$ has form
\[
e'_i=e_i* a
\]
where $e'$ is coordinate matrix of vector $e'_i$
relative basis $h$ and
$e$ is coordinate matrix of vector
$e_i$ relative basis $h$.
Therefore, coordinate matrix of image of basis equal to
produc.
Since the theorem,
matrices $g$ and $e$ are nonsingular. Therefore, matrix
is the matrix of automorphism mapping basis $e$
to basis $e'$.

Suppose elements $g_1$, $g_2$ of group $G$ and basis $e$ satisfy equation
\[
e* g_1=e* g_2
\]
Since theorems,
we get $g_1=g_2$.
This proves statement of theorem.
\end{framedPage}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.94,.94,.95}%
\begin{shadedPage}[.5\textwidth]
\setlength{\parindent}{4mm}
To prove the theorem
it is sufficient to show that
at least one transformation of left-side representation is defined for any two bases
and this transformation is unique.

Homomorphism $a$ operating on basis $e$ has form
\[
e'_i=e_i* a
\]
where $e'$ is coordinate matrix of vector $e'_i$
relative basis $h$ and
$e$ is coordinate matrix of vector
$e_i$ relative basis $h$.
Therefore, coordinate matrix of image of basis equal to
produc.
Since the theorem,
matrices $g$ and $e$ are nonsingular. Therefore, matrix
is the matrix of automorphism mapping basis $e$
to basis $e'$.

Suppose elements $g_1$, $g_2$ of group $G$ and basis $e$ satisfy equation
\[
e* g_1=e* g_2
\]
Since theorems,
we get $g_1=g_2$.
This proves statement of theorem.
\end{shadedPage}


\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.94,.94,.95}%
\begin{shadedPage}[.5\textwidth]
\setlength{\parindent}{4mm}
To prove the theorem
it is sufficient to show that
at least one transformation of left-side representation is defined for any two bases
and this transformation is unique.

Homomorphism $a$ operating on basis $e$ has form
\[
e'_i=e_i* a
\]
where $e'$ is coordinate matrix of vector $e'_i$
relative basis $h$ and
$e$ is coordinate matrix of vector
$e_i$ relative basis $h$.
Therefore, coordinate matrix of image of basis equal to
produc.
Since the theorem,
matrices $g$ and $e$ are nonsingular. Therefore, matrix
is the matrix of automorphism mapping basis $e$
to basis $e'$.

Suppose elements $g_1$, $g_2$ of group $G$ and basis $e$ satisfy equation
\[
e* g_1=e* g_2
\]
Since theorems,
we get $g_1=g_2$.
This proves statement of theorem.
\end{shadedPage}


\end{document}
```

I expected that two shaded environment will separate page and will be printed one near other like in table. But if you translate code, you will see that go in the middle of row and one after another. When I tried to use table or matrix environments, the code crashed and I was not able to finish compilation

Comment: Consider accepting one of the provided answers.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution for parallel columns could be to use `paracol` package. You define the number of columns and every time you need to change the column insert `\switchcolumn` command. This columns flow from one page to the next one, which is not possible with `minipage`.

In following code, I've also changed `framed` package by `tcolorbox` which also allow to declare breakable boxes.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{paracol}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.94,.94,.95}%

\newtcolorbox{framedPage}[1][]{%
    enhanced, breakable, sharp corners, colback=white, size=fbox, notitle,#1
}

\newtcolorbox{shadedPage}[1][]{%
    enhanced, breakable, sharp corners, colback=shadecolor, size=tight, boxrule=0pt, notitle,#1
}

\begin{document}
\title{Test File}

\begin{abstract}
In this paper I test shaded environment.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\begin{framedPage}[width=.5\textwidth, center]
\setlength{\parindent}{4mm}
To prove the theorem
it is sufficient to show that
at least one transformation of left-side representation is defined for any two bases
and this transformation is unique.

Homomorphism $a$ operating on basis $e$ has form
\[
e'_i=e_i* a
\]
where $e'$ is coordinate matrix of vector $e'_i$
relative basis $h$ and
$e$ is coordinate matrix of vector
$e_i$ relative basis $h$.
Therefore, coordinate matrix of image of basis equal to
produc.
Since the theorem,
matrices $g$ and $e$ are nonsingular. Therefore, matrix
is the matrix of automorphism mapping basis $e$
to basis $e'$.

Suppose elements $g_1$, $g_2$ of group $G$ and basis $e$ satisfy equation
\[
e* g_1=e* g_2
\]
Since theorems,
we get $g_1=g_2$.
This proves statement of theorem.
\end{framedPage}

\begin{framedPage}[width=.5\textwidth, center]
\setlength{\parindent}{4mm}
To prove the theorem
it is sufficient to show that
at least one transformation of left-side representation is defined for any two bases
and this transformation is unique.

Homomorphism $a$ operating on basis $e$ has form
\[
e'_i=e_i* a
\]
where $e'$ is coordinate matrix of vector $e'_i$
relative basis $h$ and
$e$ is coordinate matrix of vector
$e_i$ relative basis $h$.
Therefore, coordinate matrix of image of basis equal to
produc.
Since the theorem,
matrices $g$ and $e$ are nonsingular. Therefore, matrix
is the matrix of automorphism mapping basis $e$
to basis $e'$.

Suppose elements $g_1$, $g_2$ of group $G$ and basis $e$ satisfy equation
\[
e* g_1=e* g_2
\]
Since theorems,
we get $g_1=g_2$.
This proves statement of theorem.
\end{framedPage}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{shadedPage}
\setlength{\parindent}{4mm}
To prove the theorem
it is sufficient to show that
at least one transformation of left-side representation is defined for any two bases
and this transformation is unique.

Homomorphism $a$ operating on basis $e$ has form
\[
e'_i=e_i* a
\]
where $e'$ is coordinate matrix of vector $e'_i$
relative basis $h$ and
$e$ is coordinate matrix of vector
$e_i$ relative basis $h$.
Therefore, coordinate matrix of image of basis equal to
produc.
Since the theorem,
matrices $g$ and $e$ are nonsingular. Therefore, matrix
is the matrix of automorphism mapping basis $e$
to basis $e'$.

Suppose elements $g_1$, $g_2$ of group $G$ and basis $e$ satisfy equation
\[
e* g_1=e* g_2
\]
Since theorems,
we get $g_1=g_2$.
This proves statement of theorem.
\end{shadedPage}
\switchcolumn
\begin{shadedPage}
\setlength{\parindent}{4mm}
To prove the theorem
it is sufficient to show that
at least one transformation of left-side representation is defined for any two bases
and this transformation is unique.

Homomorphism $a$ operating on basis $e$ has form
\[
e'_i=e_i* a
\]
where $e'$ is coordinate matrix of vector $e'_i$
relative basis $h$ and
$e$ is coordinate matrix of vector
$e_i$ relative basis $h$.
Therefore, coordinate matrix of image of basis equal to
produc.
Since the theorem,
matrices $g$ and $e$ are nonsingular. Therefore, matrix
is the matrix of automorphism mapping basis $e$
to basis $e'$.

Suppose elements $g_1$, $g_2$ of group $G$ and basis $e$ satisfy equation
\[
e* g_1=e* g_2
\]
Since theorems,
we get $g_1=g_2$.
This proves statement of theorem.
\end{shadedPage}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, using paracol is good idea. I like it. I write now paper about left and write vector spaces. But statements are similar. So I decided to write in 2 columns. But some statements are so large that I had to cut them in few pieces to make sure that there is no empty space on the page. I think the package paracol solved this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use minipages: `\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}`  ..... `\end{minipage}` to enclose each shaded environment.

[image: A]

This is the code. Marked with `%<<<<<` the  lines changed or added.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\scrollmode
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\setlength{\OuterFrameSep}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\title{Test File}

\begin{abstract}
In this paper I test shaded environment.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\newenvironment{Shaded}{%
\def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep0pt \colorbox{shadecolor}}%
  \MakeFramed {\FrameRestore}}%
 {\endMakeFramed}

\newenvironment{framedPage}[1][\hsize]
{\MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\newenvironment{shadedPage}[1][\hsize]
{
\def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep0pt \colorbox{shadecolor}}%
\MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\begin{framedPage}[.5\textwidth]
    \setlength{\parindent}{4mm}
    To prove the theorem
    it is sufficient to show that
    at least one transformation of left-side representation is defined for any two bases
    and this transformation is unique.
    
    Homomorphism $a$ operating on basis $e$ has form
    \[
    e'_i=e_i* a
    \]
    where $e'$ is coordinate matrix of vector $e'_i$
    relative basis $h$ and
    $e$ is coordinate matrix of vector
    $e_i$ relative basis $h$.
    Therefore, coordinate matrix of image of basis equal to
    produc.
    Since the theorem,
    matrices $g$ and $e$ are nonsingular. Therefore, matrix
    is the matrix of automorphism mapping basis $e$
    to basis $e'$.
    
    Suppose elements $g_1$, $g_2$ of group $G$ and basis $e$ satisfy equation
    \[
    e* g_1=e* g_2
    \]
    Since theorems,
    we get $g_1=g_2$.
    This proves statement of theorem.
\end{framedPage}


\begin{framedPage}[.5\textwidth]
    \setlength{\parindent}{4mm}
    To prove the theorem
    it is sufficient to show that
    at least one transformation of left-side representation is defined for any two bases
    and this transformation is unique.
    
    Homomorphism $a$ operating on basis $e$ has form
    \[
    e'_i=e_i* a
    \]
    where $e'$ is coordinate matrix of vector $e'_i$
    relative basis $h$ and
    $e$ is coordinate matrix of vector
    $e_i$ relative basis $h$.
    Therefore, coordinate matrix of image of basis equal to
    produc.
    Since the theorem,
    matrices $g$ and $e$ are nonsingular. Therefore, matrix
    is the matrix of automorphism mapping basis $e$
    to basis $e'$.
    
    Suppose elements $g_1$, $g_2$ of group $G$ and basis $e$ satisfy equation
    \[
    e* g_1=e* g_2
    \]
    Since theorems,
    we get $g_1=g_2$.
    This proves statement of theorem.
\end{framedPage}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth} %<<<<  added
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.94,.94,.95}%
    \begin{shadedPage} % [.5\textwidth] changed <<<<<<
        \setlength{\parindent}{4mm}
        To prove the theorem
        it is sufficient to show that
        at least one transformation of left-side representation is defined for any two bases
        and this transformation is unique.
        
        Homomorphism $a$ operating on basis $e$ has form
        \[
        e'_i=e_i* a
        \]
        where $e'$ is coordinate matrix of vector $e'_i$
        relative basis $h$ and
        $e$ is coordinate matrix of vector
        $e_i$ relative basis $h$.
        Therefore, coordinate matrix of image of basis equal to
        produc.
        Since the theorem,
        matrices $g$ and $e$ are nonsingular. Therefore, matrix
        is the matrix of automorphism mapping basis $e$
        to basis $e'$.
        
        Suppose elements $g_1$, $g_2$ of group $G$ and basis $e$ satisfy equation
        \[
        e* g_1=e* g_2
        \]
        Since theorems,
        we get $g_1=g_2$.
        This proves statement of theorem.
    \end{shadedPage}
\end{minipage} 
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}%<<<<  added
    \definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.94,.94,.95}%
    \begin{shadedPage} % [.5\textwidth] changed <<<<<<
        \setlength{\parindent}{4mm}
        To prove the theorem
        it is sufficient to show that
        at least one transformation of left-side representation is defined for any two bases
        and this transformation is unique.
        
        Homomorphism $a$ operating on basis $e$ has form
        \[
        e'_i=e_i* a
        \]
        where $e'$ is coordinate matrix of vector $e'_i$
        relative basis $h$ and
        $e$ is coordinate matrix of vector
        $e_i$ relative basis $h$.
        Therefore, coordinate matrix of image of basis equal to
        produc.
        Since the theorem,
        matrices $g$ and $e$ are nonsingular. Therefore, matrix
        is the matrix of automorphism mapping basis $e$
        to basis $e'$.
        
        Suppose elements $g_1$, $g_2$ of group $G$ and basis $e$ satisfy equation
        \[
        e* g_1=e* g_2
        \]
        Since theorems,
        we get $g_1=g_2$.
        This proves statement of theorem.
    \end{shadedPage}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Using `\begin{minipage}{0.46\textwidth}` will create a gap between the shaded columns, for a better look.

[image: b]

Comment: It works good until text matches page. If text is longer than page, then part of the text will be lost

Comment: @Aleks Kleyn Please expand your question with this new requirement and update the MWE you provided to reflect your real document. This problem (new issues) always happens with super simplified MWEs.

Comment: The solution provided by Ignasi works better.

Answer (score 0):

Using `paracol` package there is one event which creates for me question. Sometimes it without reason creates empty lines in output. Bellow is sample code

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\scrollmode
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{paracol}
\begin{document}
\title{Test File}

\begin{abstract}
In this paper I test shaded environment.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\newenvironment{Shaded}{%
\def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep3pt \colorbox{shadecolor}}%
  \MakeFramed {\FrameRestore}}%
 {\endMakeFramed}

\newenvironment{framedPage}[1][\hsize]
{\MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\newenvironment{shadedPage}[1][\hsize]
{
\def\FrameCommand{\colorbox{shadecolor}}%
\MakeFramed{ \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}

\begin{paracol}{2}
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
representation.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
representation.
Therefore, automorphisms of left 

It remains to  prove that
the kernel of inefficiency consists only of identity.
Identity transformation
satisfies to equation
\[
v^i=v^ja_i^j
\]
Choosing values of coordinates as
$v^i=\delta^i_k$
where we selected $k$ we get
\begin{equation}
\label{identity col}
\delta^i_k=\delta^j_ka^i_j
\end{equation}
From \eqref{identity col} it follows
\[
\delta^i_k=a^i_k
\]
Since $k$ is arbitrary, we get the conclusion $a=\delta$.
\switchcolumn%
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
representation.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of rows form
a right-side linear
GL-representation.
According to the theorem
the product of automorphisms $a$ and $b$
has matrix $a*b$.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
representation.
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
representation.
Therefore, automorphisms of left 
Therefore, automorphisms of left $A$-vector space of columns form
a right-side linear
representation.
Therefore, automorphisms of left 

It remains to  prove that
the kernel of inefficiency consists only of identity.
Identity transformation
satisfies to equation
\[
v_i=v_ja^j_i
\]
Choosing values of coordinates as
$v_i=\delta^k_i$
where we selected $k$ we get
\begin{equation}
\label{identity row}
\delta^k_i=\delta^k_ja^j_i
\end{equation}
From \eqref{identity row} it follows
\[
\delta^k_i=a^k_i
\]
Since $k$ is arbitrary, we get the conclusion $a=\delta$.
\end{paracol}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I understand this is a new question and this is the place for answers. It's better that you start a new one linking to this if you want. But leaving it here almost nobody will see it.